# How long does it take for a user's Tags to update?

Tags: support, tags

Two days ago, I answered a question which had a php tag ([Incorporating a SQL LIKE in a SELECT query using Twitter/typeahead.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087724/incorporating-a-sql-like-in-a-select-query-using-twitter-typeahead-js/31088161#31088161)).

Today I notice that php doesn't appear in my tags (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990607/bisounours-tronconneuse?tab=tags).

I was wondering, how long does it takes for the tags to update? Or is it something else entirely that I am missing?

Comment: It is supposed to update overnight, but it hasnt for a day or two.